# how to use header at curl in php

Tags: php, curl

hi how can i perfom this curl command in php?

```
curl -X POST "https://api.*****.com/ecc/v1/regions/ir-thr-at1/servers/d13****-9703******/power-on" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Apikey a4****82-0***-4***f-a***e-e*********3"
```

Request URL is

```
https://napi.arvancloud.com/ecc/v1/regions/ir-thr-at1/servers/d13317d1-9703-4801-b07e-b0dd45a3baa6/power-on
```

i try this code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://napi.arvancloud.com/ecc/v1/regions/ir-thr-at1/servers/d13317d1-9703-4801-b07e-b0dd45a3baa6/power-on");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
         http_build_query(array('Authorization' => 'Apikey a42727*********')));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
 echo $server_output;
```

but return unauthorized the key is absolutely ok

those who voted  instead of - solved this!!!

**EDIT**

```
$headers = array(
    'Authentication:Apikey 320f8**************fa',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);


if ($server_output === false)
{
    // throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
```

it also return **Unauthenticated**

i tested on postman it is ok but not my code :
the postman did this:

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXTSX.png)

[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQPdM.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265825/2943403 , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321923/2943403 , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296119/2943403

Comment: Have you tried php.net? Examples are here https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php. If you are having a specific issue please update the question with what it is and the code.

Comment: i try this code

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://napi.arvancloud.com/ecc/v1/regions/ir-thr-at1/servers/d13317d1-9703-4801-b07e-b0dd45a3baa6/power-on");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
         http_build_query(array('Authorization' => 'Apikey a42727*********')));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
 echo $server_output;
   


but return unauthorization the key is ok

Comment: @user3783243 please check out the question again

Answer (score 0):

Using php-curl, make sure it is installed and activated on your machine before trying this solution :

```
    $request = curl_init("https://napi.arvancloud.com/ecc/v1/regions/ir-thr-at1/servers/d13317d1-9703-4801-b07e-b0dd45a3baa6/power-on
");
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Set Post Method
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); // Set POST Data
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Apikey a4****82-0***-4***f-a***e-e*********3', 'accept: application/json')); // Request Header
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Enable Response Return
        $response = curl_exec($request); // Execute Request
```

Comment: hi @elkhayder
i use  echo    $response; but nothing shows there

Comment: PHP Warning:  http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object.

Comment: you put your data in $data array, if you have none to post remove that line

Comment: take a look at question again @elkhayder